# Embedded YouTube video ignores z-Index, but works if I open the Dev-Tools

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, z-index

First WTF YouTube!

Second I already tried the &wmode=Opaque and &wmode=transparent.

I don't know what to do, I tried nearly everything and it won't work.....my iframe always is always in front of any object. The weirdest thing is if I open the Chrome Dev-Tools it works and isn't ignoring the z-index but if I try it normal in the browser it doesn't work

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LYtxs0ruutM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media ;gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="--aspect-ratio: 315 / 560;"></iframe>
```

Thats my iframe....

the aspect-ratio is for the responsivity.

```
iframe { --video-width: 40vw; width: 40%; height: calc(var(--video-width) * var(--aspect-ratio));box-shadow: 1.5em 1.5em #00000013;}
```

And thats my CSS-Code

Guys I hope you can help me, im near to go berserk :(

Already thanks for your awnser

Comment: my main language is Russian. please rephrase your problem. maybe I can help you.

Comment: Первый WTF YouTube!

Во-вторых, я уже попробовал &wmode=Opaque и &wmode=transparent.

Я не знаю, что делать, я попробовал почти все и это не будет работать.....my iframe всегда перед любым объектом. Самое странное, что если я открою Chrome Dev-Tools, он работает и не игнорирует z-индекс, но если я попробую его нормально в браузере, он не будет работать.


Это мой iframe....
Аспект-рационом - это ответственность.

И это мой CSS-код

Ребята, надеюсь, вы мне поможете, я уже почти ушел в отрыв.
Спасибо за вашу заявку.
Переведено с помощью www.DeepL.com/Translator (бесплатная версия)

Comment: I mean in english. until I figured out your problem. paraphrase if you can. or make a diagram.

Comment: Ok sorry hahaha

Comment: I have an object, that needs to be in front of the embedded video but the video ignores all z- indexes ive set, even if I set the z-index to 10000000. My problem is I can't put an object in front of the video..

Comment: can you be more specific? what kind of object? give the code with iframe and object

Comment: it is a div with white background, .animation {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 511;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

Comment: give the code to the snipped complete.